# Why is data stored in local storage not available when I call it even though I can see it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yammer

Morning,

I have built a prototype app in Angular that authenticates against the Yammer API. 
I have an issue where it authenticates, stores some data in local storage and then I can use it.

here is my API call to get some groups from Yammer. Note, I have already authenticated and my access token ('Bearer') is already in local storage as I can see it.

[image]

And here is the Auth.GetAccessToken() code:

[image]

When yamGetAllGroups is called the Bearer in the headers in empty.

Any help would be appreciated, I was thinking it was something to do with async or something in Angular? ie. it makes the json call to Yammer before it actually reads local storage?

thanks
Russ

Comment: `getItem()` only takes one argument, the `key`

Comment: `token` is only referenced by `return token`.  Where is it set? If you are getting null returns, perhaps nothing sets token.

Comment: Good point. @charlietfl. . As usual you look at what you think is the issue when some fundamentals are wrong. I can't test at the moment but if this solves the issue I will mark as the answer.

Comment: @Paul. The token is getting set as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Is getAccessToken() getting invoked, can you print what's in pa_expires? Also show us how Auth is injected.

Comment: @RuSs Nothing in `getAccessToken` sets `token`, so the `token` returned by `getAccessToken` is from an enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Some proxies and ssl inspectors (Bluecoat especially) tend to modify/annul the token in the request header so you may want to test this outside your corp network to see if that helps.
2. There is a LocalStorage implementation [here](https://github.com/iogbole/yam_jssdk_LocalStorage/blob/master/index.html) . Take a peak and see if it helps